# Operator that adds a value to all elements of an set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am searching for an operator that adds a (constant) value to all members of a set (of integers). If it can be described as a function with two parameters, then I search for a function $F(S,a)$ that maps set $S = \{1,4,7\}$ to set $F(S,a) = \{1+a, 4+a, 7+a\}$.

Is there any well known operator that acts like this?

Comment: Sounds like you just defined one.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Still, it would be nicer for my purpose, if there exists an universally valid and known operator, which does not need to be defined.

Comment: I think the distinction between those two things is very vague. Consider the Dirac delta, for example.

Comment: For any $S\subset \Bbb R$ and any $r\in \Bbb R$ it is customary that $S+r=r+S=\{x+r: x\in S\}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write $S+a$ for $\{s+a:s\in S\}$.